# Asymptotics for $\zeta^{(n)}(2)$

Tags: riemann-zeta

Let $\zeta^{(n)}(2)$ be the $n$-th derivative of the Riemann zeta function, evaluated at $2$. Numerical experiments seem to suggest that $|\zeta^{(n)}(2)|\sim n!$, in the sense that $|\zeta^{(n)}(2)|/n!\rightarrow 1 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Is this a theorem, or is it just another of those numerical illusions that often happen when experimenting with the zeta function?

Comment: It might help to consider what $f(s) = 1/(s - 1)$ does.

Comment: I realize there is an oscillation, but I was thinking of the magnitude. I have now edited my post.

Comment: Stated equivalently the OP wants asymptotics for the series$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\ln^n{(k)}}{k^2}$$which appears to be asymptotic to $n!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} (\frac{\zeta^{(k)}(2)}{k!}-(-1)^k) (s-2)^k =\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}$$ It extends analytically to the whole complex plane [thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) the Taylor series converges for all $s$ and for $r$ arbitrary large, $$\lim_{k\to \infty} (\frac{\zeta^{(k)}(2)}{k!}-(-1)^k)r^k =0$$